# Reset bindingsource of datagridview does not work

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a `dataset(data.xsd)` retrieving data from database, a `Bindingsourc(bs)` from a table of this `data.xsd` and a `datagridview(dgview)` bounded to this `bs`

now when I insert or delete an item I call the `ResetBinding` function of `bs` 
but the `dgview` doesn't update by that:

```
     bs.ResetBinding(false);
     ((BindingSource)dgview.DataSource).ResetBindings(false);
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem

the `DataSource` that I bound the `bs` to it should get the new data from database and then call `ResetBinding()` function:

```
bstableAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
bs.ResetBinding(false);
```